# Ho to dynamically change the assigned eventHandler to a specific input element?

Tags: angular, typescript, events

I have a child component which generates a couple of input fields dynamically in a parent component.

```
<app-xxx *ngFor="let el of fieldsElements" 
         [ngModel]="fieldsElements[el.name]"
         ...
         ...
         (keydown)="myFunction(yyy, zzz)">
</app-xxx>
```

The issue is that I would like to call **`myFunction()`** using **`click()`** **eventHandler** if the input has a specific name, but for the rest, I want to keep **`(keydown)`**. Or let's say for one of the generated input fields, I want to assign **`(click)`** instead of **`(keydown)`**. Example:

```
<app-xxx *ngFor="let el of fieldsElements" 
         [ngModel]="fieldsElements[el.name]"
         ...
         ...
         (click)="myFunction(yyy, zzz)">
</app-xxx>
```

How can I achieve this dynamically in the **HTML/View**? I have been trying couple of options using **`*ngIf`** and some other options within the **`ts`** file using an if-statement and **`addEventListener()`** etc.
None of them did help.

Any hint or idea?

Comment: `*ngIf` is a good way to do that, how did you try using `*ngIf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most efficient will be use a variable and use the way 'variable && function'. Only if variable is true the function is executed

```
<app-xxx *ngFor="let el of fieldsElements" 
         [ngModel]="fieldsElements[el.name]"
         ...
         ...
         (click)="el.allowClick && myFunction(yyy, zzz)">
         (keydown)="el.allowKeydown && myFunction(yyy, zzz)">
</app-xxx>
```

**Update** so, e.g. if your fieldsElements are an array of elements, like

```
fieldsElements=[
  {name:"name1",allowClick:true},
  {name:"name2",allowKeyDown:true},
  {name:"name3"}]
```

"name1" execute function when (click), "name2" when (keyDown) and "name3" not execute anything

Comment: Sounds elegant, but the second part looks weird somehow. What do mean exactly with `...some case` What would be `el` in case of `ts` file? The answer isn't really clear

Comment: your fieldsElements must be an array of elements, just add new properties, e.g. you has `fieldsElements=[{name:"name1",allowClick:true},{name:"name2·,allowKeyDown:true},{name:"name3"}]`, so "name1" execute function when (click), "name2" when (keyDown) and "name3" not execute anything. I edit the answer for clarify

Comment: Yes. I got what you mean. Great idea/hint. Thump up. Working fine.

Comment: @k.vincent, thanks for the upvoted, but thinking... your <app-xxx is a component, ergo (click) and (keydown) are `@Output()`s. That's mean that you need declare it in your component and "emit some value" when some happens. If you don't emit, the functions never happens.

Comment: Yes, true. I do have them and works fine. One small thing I'am facing right now. When I pass: `$event.target.value` to the `(click)` as a second parameter, it looks that I can't access `value` this way. e.g. `(click)="el.allowClick && myFunction(yyy, $event.target.value)"` But for `(keydown)="el.allowKeydown && myFunction(yyy, $event.target.value)"` it looks fine. Even my IDE says: `Unresolved variable value`. Any idea? In general the rest works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using multiple templates inside the `<app-xxx>` tag and toggle them via [NgIf-Else](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else)

Comment: This seems no to be enough. Have been trying this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *ngIf (and/or if/else).

```
<div *ngFor=(etc. etc)>
    <div *ngIf="name === 'somename'" (click)="myFunction()">
    etc...
    <div>
    <div *ngIf="name !== 'somename'" (keydown)="myFunction()">
    etc...
    </div>
</div>
```

So you're not really dynamically switching handlers, you're just writing out the element you want based on the name you're looking for. But the result is the same.

Comment: Have bee trying `ng-template` and using `*ngIf="fieldsElements[el.name] == 'xxx'"`, but it didn't help. The assignment of eventHandler should be based on `fieldsElements[el.name]`. This means I can assign it after the input elements are in the view and check if `fieldsElements[el.name] == 'xxx'`

Comment: @k.vincent `*ngIf="fieldsElements[el.name] == 'xxx'"` will not work because `fieldsElements` is an array and `el.name` is a string not index. Try `*ngIf="el.name == 'xxx'"`

Comment: I . guess the . right thing to do then would be to recommend an edit. I didn't actually mean "this" as in a reference to the object, I just meant "this bit". I updated.